# Can't delete user directory on CentOS

Tags: linux, permissions, centos, directory-permissions

I'm stuck.

I did a simple useradd. I had user -> mark and assigned directory -> /home/mark. Here i've installed a software. Later I've deleted mark and now i can't delete /home/mark. With root account I tried to:

a) Change permission to 777 -> Permission denied

b) Delete directory with

```
rm -rf /home/mark
```

Permission denied

c) Nautilus

```
sudo nautilus
```

Could not parse arguments: Can't open display (what??)

There's no way for me to remove this directory from my server. Here's my permissions list

```
ls -la /home/mark

drwx------ 5  502  502    4096 10 ago 13:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root    4096 10 ago 16:13 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1  502  502     366 10 ago 13:46 .bash_history
-rwxrwxrwx 1  502  502      18 10 mag 20:45 .bash_logout
-rwxrwxrwx 1  502  502     176 10 mag 20:45 .bash_profile
-rwxrwxrwx 1  502  502     124 10 mag 20:45 .bashrc
drwxrwxrwx 2  502  502    4096 12 nov  2010 .gnome2
drwxrwxrwx 2  502  502    4096 10 ago 14:28 .mozilla
drwxrwxrwx 2  502  502    4096 10 ago 14:28 mypackage
-rwxrwxrwx 1  502  502 4131518 10 ago 05:06 mypackage.tar.gz
```

Any idea?

p.s. On GNOME when I right-click this folder (of course I can't open it) I see on Permissions tab that Owner and Group are still assigned to mark's ID. I can see Owner -> 502 - user #502 (it was mark) and Group -> 502. All forms are greyed-out and I can't edit them.

Answer (score 1):

To delete the user mark and his data (/hom/mark), as root type this:

```
#userdel -r mark
```

EDIT : try this

```
chattr -i mark
rm -rf mark
```

You said that you cannot `chown` this directory, if the command above does not work, i suggest `fsck` on the system:

```
#shutdown -r -F now
```

And try after checking the filesyetemn to remove the mark folder.

Comment: result is -> userdel: user 'mark' does not exist. 'mark' has been already deleted so i suppose that it's the reason why these kind of commands can't work.

Comment: @user1274113 : when you're on the root dir (cd /) and you do an (ls -l) what's the permissions of /home (not /home/mark)?

Comment: I have this:

drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 10 ago 16:13 home

Comment: @user1274113 : and when you try this : (chown -R root:root /home/mark)?

Comment: Still "Operation not permitted". This problem is just incredible

Answer (score 0):

Log in as root

```
cd /home
chmod -R 0777 mark
rm -fr mark
```

should do the trick.

Then edit /etc/passwd /etc/shadow

Comment: no way :( "Operation not permitted" and in /etc/passwd there are no strings about 'mark' and its directories.

Comment: i can't delete /home/mark. i get "Operation not permitted" over and over again.

Comment: Juat shutdown to single user mode.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure no running process associated with that directory.

```
[root@ap0003 tmp]# fuser /home/spatel
/home/spatel:         1196c  1243c
[root@ap0003 tmp]# ps aux | grep 1196
spatel    1196  0.0  0.0  66120  1540 pts/0    Ss   09:41   0:00 -bash
root      1889  0.0  0.0  61228   764 pts/0    S+   11:38   0:00 grep 1196
```

Comment: i get this:

`code`[root@whatever tmp]# fuser /home/spatel
Impossibile fare stat di /home/spatel: No such file or directory
Impossibile fare stat di /home/spatel: No such file or directory
[root@whatever tmp]# ps aux | grep 1196
root     15234  0.0  0.0 103284   832 ttyp0    S+   19:30   0:00 grep 1196`code`

Comment: Run this command it will kill all process related your directory [root@whatever tmp]# fuser -k /home/mark