# PHP mkdir() fails because file exists, but rmdir fails because it doesn't

Tags: php, shell, file, unix

I have a php script which includes roughly the lines:

```
$dirname = '/directory/subdirectory';

if ( mkdir($dirname) ) {
   // do something...
} else {
   // couldn't make the directory, error out
}
```

Which is returning an error. `error_get_last()` returns:

```
Array
(
    [type] => 2
    [message] => mkdir(): File exists
    [file] => /scripts/the_script.php
    [line] => 155
)
```

However, the directory doesn't appear to exist on my filesystem (either in the GUI or command line), and `rmdir /directory/subdirectory` fails with "No such file or directory".

Help!

**EDIT**: For those following along - for clarity I've removed a previous edit/update about filename conflicts after resolving it independently. The above problem remains.

**EDIT II**
**Permissions** : There are no permissions issues I'm fairly confident. I can use the exact same code to create a differently named subdirectory in the same directory without issue. It seems to be more the case that PHP believes a certain subdir exists when the system says otherwise.

This is all running on a virtualbox centos machine, with a shared directory mounted to my host machine. The directory doesn't appear in either machines' shell instances or over ssh.

**EDIT III** 
To confirm what people may have been thinking, it looks like this issue is actually unrelated to PHP. In the command line I can run:

```
$ mkdir /path/to/directory
mkdir: cannot create directory '/path/to/directory': File exists
$ rmdir /path/to/directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/path/to/directory': No such file or directory
```

And just to top it off...

```
$ rm /path/to/directory
rm: cannot remove '/path/to/directory': Is a directory
```

What

Comment: Because : `$dir ` is not `$dirname` , `$dirname` does not even exists as variable in your code refrence

Comment: @ArshSingh ah haha ha that's cheered me up. Well spotted.

Comment: @ArshSingh Sorry that was just a typo in my question not my actual code! The variables do match.

Comment: Do you have permission in the PHP owner or in the file structure to add the folder? If a parent folder prevents group (for example) writing access then the `mkdir` will be disallowed. Check your permissions.

Comment: Check if it's actually a directory with [`is_dir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php).

Comment: Yes, no permissions issues I'm fairly confident. I can use the exact same code to create a differently named subdirectory in the same directory without issue. It seems to be more the case that PHP believes a *certain* subdir exists when the system says otherwise

Comment: as a punt try running `clearstatcache()` (although this probably won't make a difference )

Comment: And by "doesn't exist on my filesystem" does that mean the directory does not appear on any observation directory tree such as in SFTP / SSH etc?

Comment: @Martin this is all running on a virtualbox centos machine, with a shared directory mounted to my host machine. The directory doesn't appear in either machines' shell instances or over ssh. And unfortunately clearstatcache() hasn't helped :(

Comment: @Martin thanks very much. I've resolved the file/directory name conflict but the original problem remains - so I've updated the question again to try and keep it as clear as possible

Comment: does this link help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903869/cant-delete-user-directory-on-centos also try perhaps rebooting and that'll clear any temporary inconsistencies on the filesystem....

Comment: @Martin turning it off and on again worked in the end, which is deeply unsatisfactory. Thanks for all your help

Comment: It is a gritter that that provides a solution without a resolution, this was a curious issue. @s-low hope it doesn't appear again

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to check first if the Directory exists before creating it in the first place. Secondly, you should be sure you have the appropriate Permissions on the Directory in which the new Directory is to be created (the Parent of the New One to be created), otherwise, you may run into Permission issues. The code below illustrates this idea:

```
    <?php
        $dirName        = __DIR__  . "/directory/subdirectory";
        $dirOK          = false;

        if(!file_exists($dirName)){
            // SPLIT THE DIRECTORY NAME AT "/" INTO AN ARRAY,
            // IN AN ATTEMPT TO EXTRACT THE PARENT DIRECTORY
            $dirParts   = preg_split("\/", $dirName);

            // REMOVE THE LAST ELEMENT OF THE ARRAY TO GET THE PARENT DIRECTORY
            $subDir     = array_pop($dirParts);

            // BUILD UP THE PARENT DIRECTORY WITH IMPLODE
            $parentDir  = implode("/", $dirParts);

            // SET THE APPROPRIATE PERMISSION ON THE PARENT DIRECTORY
            // BEFORE ATTEMPTING TO CREATE A SUB-DIRECTORY INSIDE IT
            if( is_dir($parentDir) ){
                chmod($parentDir, 0777);

                // NOW, HAVING THE APPROPRIATE PERMISSION; CREATE THE SUB-DIRECTORY
                $dirOK  = mkdir($dirName . "/{$subDir}", 0777);
            }

            if($dirOK){
                // DIRECTORY WAS SUCCESSFULLY CREATED,
                // DO SOMETHING HERE IF NECESSARY
            }else{
                // DIRECTORY COULD NOT BE CREATED,
                // DO SOMETHING HERE IF NECESSARY
            }
        }
```